# Backup mails after downgrading from google business to google apps

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-account

My Google Business 30 days trial has expired today. I am wondering whether my saved mails in my mail box won't be deleted after I will downgrade from Google Business to Google Apps? if my mails are going to be deleted i would like to know if there is a way to save them before i cancel my Google Business account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

messages will not be deleted but if users are over the Free Editions 10gb quota, they'll be unable to send/receive mail after the downgrade.

Confirm your users are under quota and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that this issue wasn't described clearly in the Google's papers i have read on this subject.
Anyway I can say that after the downgrade  my mails were keep faithfully and none of my data was deleted. :)